# load an image when selecting a jstree node

Tags: jquery, jstree

new to jstree and java scripts. Need to create a jstree and when clicked on a node, I need to load an image. Clicking on different nodes should load different images. So far, I have this:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Tree</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <Script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#test1").jstree({   


         "xml_data" : {  

             "ajax" : {  

                 "url" : "/URL/tree.xml

             },  

             "xsl" : "nest" 

         },  


         "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types"] 


     });  

    });

</Script>

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='tree.xml1'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've asked quite a mouthful, but I think this will help you. This is based on the code you provided:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tree</title>

    <link href="jqueryUI/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jstree/jquery.jstree.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#test1").jstree({   
                "html_data" : {
                    "data" : "<li id='root'><a href='#'>My Images</a><ul>" +
                        "<li id='image1.png'><a href='#'>Image 1</a></li>" +
                        "<li id='image2.png'><a href='#'>Image 2</a></li>" +
                        "<li id='image3.png'><a href='#'>Image 3</a></li>" +
                        "</ul></li>"
                },

                "plugins" : ["themes", "html_data", "ui","types"] 
            }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
                $("#imageDisplay").html("Load " + data.rslt.obj.attr("id") + " here"); 
            });  
        });

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td><div id='test1'></div></td>
        <td><div id='imageDisplay'></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, there are no actual images for this code to display, but I'm sure you can fill in the blanks. Also note that I used the "html_data" plugin instead of "xml_data", because I don't know how your XML file is formatted.

Comment: I thank you for your response. Since I will be building the nodes from xml file dynamically, it will be challenging to click a node and load the corresponding image. I really dont know how am I going to do this yet.

Comment: Thank you Dan for this. I am just learning jquery and need to know if the task I am trying to do is feasible with jquery. I have hundreds of images that generated with a program. These images start with primary number as the jstree nodes. Jstree nodes and images share the primary key value that each has. Clicking on a node on the jstree, I need to load all the images start witht that common number. Can I do this with jquerr? Thanks again for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the image names and IDs ahead of time, why not do this all in CSS? No programming required and updates to the image is all done in the css file.

```
#f_def.jstree-open > a > ins{
    background: url("../images/f_def.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent ! important;
}

#f_def.jstree-open > a > ins,
#f_def.jstree-open > a{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}


#f_def.jstree-closed > a > ins {
    /* Use Default Icon for closed */
}
```

Comment: can you aloborate on this. Having hundereds of images and loading them based on the node clicked on jstree, is this doable with css?

Comment: @SeanKaplan sure, but you need to be able to differentiate each unique image. The example above does it by ID per jstree node.